# Lookup issue for multirow comparison in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have two datasets as below

**FirstOne**:

```
CFamily CName Cno Role

AFamily A     1   Main

AFamily B     2   Secondary
```

**SecondOne**:

```
CName Cno Product

A     1   P1

A     1   P2

B     2   P1

B     2   P2
```

The table is mapped with Second Dataset and grouped by `CFamily` using Lookup. Now, under each group(`CFamily`), I need to show an extra row to show Contact with Role(Main). I used Lookup expression as follows.

```
Lookup(Fields!Cno.Value,Fields!Cno.Value,Fields!CName,"FirstOne")
```

But it is returning `B` most of the times. sometimes. Is it possible to show only Contact with Role "Main".

Comment: How are you getting your data? Sql, web services, ...?

Comment: The data for FirstOne is coming from SQL Server and the data for SecondOne dataset is coming from Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

The SSRS Lookup functions are unreliable - it would be better to do this upstream in a Dataset e.g. with a SQL join.

If you are stuck using an SSRS expression, I would try casting the datatypes for comparison - sometimes SSRS decides internally on varying datatypes which can cause this to break.

e.g.

`=Lookup(CInt(Fields!Cno.Value),CInt(Fields!Cno.Value),Fields!CName,"FirstOne")`

Answer (score 0):

Evidently Mike's answer didn't work. It should work if that's all the data in the tables - though so should have your expression.

If there is other data and you just want the **Role** with **Main**, you can concatenate the fields for the lookup:

```
=Lookup(CSTR(Fields!Cno.Value) & "|Main", CSTR(Fields!Cno.Value) & "|" & CSTR(Fields!Role.Value), Fields!CName, "FirstOne")
```